# ActiveMQ prevents our application server from being stopped

Tags: java, wildfly, activemq-classic

Under certain circumstances, ActiveMQ prevents our application server from stopping.
We are using the following scenario:
ActiveMQ version 5.16.3 is integrated into our Wildfly 25 via the ActiveMQResourceAdapter. The application server is located in a cluster of 2 servers. The active node is controlled via a lease database locker.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
  <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${WILDFLY_INSTANCE_DATA_DIR}/activemq/jdbcPersistenceAdapter" dataSource="#activeMQDS" createTablesOnStartup="true" lockKeepAlivePeriod="4000">
    <locker>            
      <lease-database-locker lockAcquireSleepInterval="8000" leaseHolderId="${HOSTNAME}:${HOSTPORT}" maxAllowableDiffFromDBTime="2000"/>
    </locker>
    <statements>
      <statements tablePrefix="WILDFLY_" />
    </statements>
  </jdbcPersistenceAdapter>
 </persistenceAdapter>
```

If the application server is stopped that is not currently the active node, the Java thread continues. A java dump shows that the stop process is blocked by stopping ActiveMQ.

```
 public void stop()
  {
    this.log.debug(new StringBuilder().append("Stop: ").append(getInfo()).toString());
    this.started.compareAndSet(true, false);
    synchronized (this.endpointWorkers) {
      while (this.endpointWorkers.size() > 0) {
        ActiveMQEndpointActivationKey key = (ActiveMQEndpointActivationKey)this.endpointWorkers.keySet().iterator().next();
        endpointDeactivation(key.getMessageEndpointFactory(), key.getActivationSpec());
      }
    }
    //BLOCKED HERE
    synchronized (this) {
      if (this.broker != null) {
        if (this.brokerStartThread.isAlive()) {
          this.brokerStartThread.interrupt();
        }
        ServiceSupport.dispose(this.broker);
        this.broker = null;
      }
      if (this.reconnectingXaResource != null) {
        this.reconnectingXaResource.stop();
      }
    }

    this.bootstrapContext = null;
    this.reconnectingXaResource = null;
  }
```

The stop is only carried out if the outstanding start can be completed which blocks or enables the synchronized. Since the cluster node is not the active ActiveMQ node, it remains alive until the active partner relinquishes his role.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you not using the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis that comes pre-configured in WildFly?

Comment: The use of ActiveMQ via the resource adapter has historical reasons. Before we switched to the Wildfly, we had a jBoss eap 6.4 in use and the HornetQ used there could not communicate with our C ++ clients. During the migration phase to wildfly, we wanted to change the system as little as possible.

Comment: What protocol are your C++ clients using?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by, "we wanted to change the system as little as possible." ActiveMQ Artemis was actually originally based on HornetQ so if you wanted as little change as possible I would expect that sticking with the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis that ships with WildFly would give you the best result there. Can you shed any light on this?